# javascript:how to populate the listview from the database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, listview, cordova

How should i code for the listview for the data that will be extracted from the DATABASE?

it is like this..

**script**

```
 function querySuccess(tx, results) 
            {
                    var len = results.rows.length;
                    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
                    for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
                    {
                        console.log("Row = " + i + " name= " + results.rows.item(i).name+ " address=  " + results.rows.item(i).address+ " roll_no= " + results.rows.item(i).roll_no);
                        document.getElementById("list_view").innerhtml  = results.rows.item(i).name;
                    }
            }
```

**html**

```
 <divid="list_view" style="float:left; width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
                <ul style="float:left; width:100%; list-style:none; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
                    <div style=" border-bottom-color:#CCCCCC; border-bottom:ridge; "> <li style="font-size:18px"></li></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**AM I CORRECT??**
**how to set the data retrieved from the database as the div content?**
I am somewhere wrong,because in the output i don't get anything.except the header.

Comment: You didn't say how did you get data?? As far as I know you can't connect to a db using js. Db is server side, js is client side. If results is empty you get the header. Even if results would not be empty you would not get what you want, you would only get results.rows.item(i).name as a string with nothing else. Your script would just rewrite the div content. You must create elements, append them to dom, etc. Anyway... either I don't get what you are trying to do, either you are doing something terribly wrong there. Post the script loading data pls., or confirm results has something in it.

Comment: zozo Sir,i need to populate the data that will be fetched from the database and viewed in the format of listview.....i hope i made myself clear...instead of we giving the data in the li tag,i want it to come from the database directly.it will come till the data in the database.that is why i put it inside the for loop.

Comment: the point is its not displaying in the div content..its blank

Comment: this line document.getElementById("list_view").innerhtml = results.rows.item(i).name; is removing all content of your div, and fills it with whatever is in results.rows.item(i).name. Also you didn't say how you got the results parameter. If you checked it and is correct I can provide you with a simple solution to your problem. If not... there is your biggest problem.